# How to put the time string into the fish shell's prompt?

Tags: command-line, prompt, fish

Currently I use [this](https://github.com/fishpkg/fish-prompt-metro) theme for fish, installed using [fisher](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fisher).

This is how it shows up now:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like the time string (e.g. `19:19`) to be shown before the `/m` or after `react` or after the part with the green background.

I have searched a little on this website but did not find anything similar.

I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to edit your `fish_prompt` function, perhaps using `funced fish_prompt`.

It will need to include something like:

```
echo -n (date +%H:%M)" "
```

(The `echo -n ()` part is required to remove the new line that the `date` command outputs.)

If you want it to appear at the very beginning, insert that as the first line of the function.